# Can't create an extended partition

Tags: partitioning

I'm trying to install 12.10 on a Lenovo Ideapad u410.  I shrank my windows 8 partition and want to create an extended partition in the unallocated space.  But when I try to create a partition there, "Primary" is the only available option.

Current table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqepa.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the maximum number of primary plus extended partitions on a DOS MBR drive is 4, and given the fact that you already have 7 partitions, it would appear that you have a GPT ([GUID partition table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table))

Extended partitions are therefore redundant on a GPT.  Just make another partition on the drive and use it as you wish.

Comment: ah ok - so I really want to make 3 partitions - one for the OS, home for /home and one for swap.  I can just make them all as primary?

Comment: That's correct.